# How to load csv file into SparkSession

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I am learning PySpark from some online source.  I googled around and found how I could read csv file into Spark DataFrame using the following codes

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark_df = spark.read.csv('my_file.csv', header=True)
pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()
```

However, on the online site I am learning, it loads the csv file somehow into SparkSession without telling the audience how to do it.  That is, when I typed (on the online site's browser)

```
print(spark.catalog.listTables())
```

The following output returns.

```
[Table(name='my_file', database=None, description=None, tableType='TEMPORARY', isTemporary=True)]
```

When I tried to print the catalog as above, I got an empty list back.

Is there anyway how to put the csv file into the SparkSession?  I have tried to google for this but most of what I found is how to load csv into Spark DataFrame like I showed above.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(#type the app name).getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('invoice.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. The command

`print(spark.catalog.listTables())`

Still yields empty list.  Perhaps I did something wrong on "Type the app name"?  There I typed "my_file.csv".

Comment: you need to add `df.createOrReplaceTempView('my_file')` - this will register dataframe in catalog

Answer (score 0):

It seems how to do this is left far behind where it should be on the online site.

```
sdf = spark.read.csv('my_file.csv', header=True)
pdf = sdf.toPandas()
spark_temp = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
spark_temp.createOrReplaceTempView('my_file')
print(spark.catalog.listTables())

[Table(name='my_file', database=None, description=None, tableType='TEMPORARY', isTemporary=True)]
```

One question remains though.  I cannot use pd.read_csv('my_file.csv') directly.  It resulted in some merge error or something.

Answer (score 0):

This can work:

```
df = my_spark.read.csv("my_file.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('my_file')
print(my_spark.catalog.listTables())
```